# Derivation of Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I am reading Lorentz transformation from Robert Resnick book. It is given that

> $x'= a_{11}x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z +a_{14}t$
>   $y'= a_{21}x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z +a_{24}t$
>   $z'= a_{31}x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z +a_{34}t$
>   $t'= a_{41}x + a_{42}y + a_{43}z +a_{44}t$

While solving coefficients of $y'$, as the two frames are coinciding at t=0 and one of the frame is moving with $v$ velocity in $+x$ direction. So we can say that $y'\,axis$ is always perpendicular to x and z axis. So $y'$ has nothing to do with x and y so $a_{21}$ and $a_{23}$ are zero.

But, why $a_{42}$ and $a_{43}$ are zero?

How to use the postulates to derive these coefficients which I have asked because other coefficients are given in other books also. But these coefficients are not explained explicitly. Please give me some approach.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what your assumptions are.

Comment: Assumptions are the postulates of relativity and the two additional postulates: homogeneity and isotropism of space and time( which is given in Robert Resnick book)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations

Comment: Is this from *"Basic Concepts in Relativity and Early Quantum Theory"*? If so, I see this:  "For reasons of symmetry, we assume $t'$ does not depend on $y$ and $z$.  Otherwise, clocks place symmetrically in the $y-z$ plane (such as at $+y, -y,+z,-z$) about the $x$-axis would appear to disagree from $S'$, which would contradict the isotropy of space. Hence, $a_{42}=a_{43}=0$."

Comment: From relativity

Comment: @Alfred Centuari, this is exactly what is written in the book. Please explain this a bit more. What symmetry in this case author wanted to imply?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Lorentz transformation similar to  a rotation in $x$ and $t$ plane ( if the velocity is along x axis) , so basically its just intermixing time and only $x$ component of space. So $a_{42} $ and $a_{43} $ will be zero as there is no velocity along $y$ and $z$ axis.

Comment: No, I can make this conclusion for Galilean transformation easily. But for Lorentz transformation, I think we have to use somewhat more strong argument to reach this conclusion.

Comment: but Galilean transformation does not affect the time co-ordinate, so it can't be a rotation.